# Merging in Unix

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, merge

I have a CSV file with vertical bars (`|`) as the delimiter, like below, for which I need to apply merging technique in Unix. The file contains hundreds of thousands of records (four fields), but I gave only five records for ease of reading.

```
field1 |field2 | field3 |field4|
1|abc|def|ghi|
4|ijk|
|lmn|
5||opq|rst|
8|
uvw||xyz|
10|hjg|jsh|nbm|
```

And I want the output result as

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|
1|abc|def|ghi|
4|ijk||lmn|
5||opq|rst|
8|uvw||xyz|
10|hjg|jsh|nbm|
```

Comment: so you want leading and trailing spaces around the pipe symbols as well as any newlines except those after every 4th pipe symbol removed? is that correct?

Comment: I’m sorry if you’re stuck with data that look like this.   While the answers that have been presented will handle this mangled structure in the best case, it is very precarious (sensitive) to data corruption.   For example, if you have a file where every record is split across two lines (every line has two fields), and **one** line gets deleted (or totally scrambled), the rebuilt (output) file will be wrong from there on.   You might want to specify that the first field (and only the first field) of each line is a number, so error checking becomes possible.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S. Is it possible for parts of multiple records to be on the same line?  For example, `1|abc|def|` / `ghi|4|ijk|` / `|lmn|`?  And is it possible for a field to be split across lines?  For example, `10|hjg|j` / `sh|nbm|`?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':loop /\(.*|\)\{4\}.*/ !{N; s/\n//; b loop}; s/ *| */|/g' file
```

**The command dissected:**

`:loop`

The `:` signals a label that we can use for branches. "loop" is just the name that I chose for the label.

`/\(.*|\)\{4\}.*/`

Is a line selector regex that matches lines that contain 4 pipe symbols, each allowed to be preceded by zero or more arbitrary characters (`.*|`), with zero or more arbitrary characters allowed to follow the last pipe.

`!{ ... }`

Applies the commands in the brackets to any line that did *not* match the previous regex.

`N; s/\n//; b loop`

`N` concatenes the current line in *pattern space* with a newline symbol and the next line from the source file, then `s/\n//` removes the newline symbol and `b loop` branches back to the label we have defined in the start, so the concatenated line will be compared against the regex again.

Lastly

`s/ *| */|/g`

will be applied to any line in pattern space before it is output. This removes any spaces around pipe symbols.

Comment: this code not working!

Comment: does too for me with GNU sed 4.4

Comment: sed --version
My `sed` (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: so i have just confirmed that this works just fine with GNU sed 4.2.2 as well. you probably made a typo, dude.

Comment: Well, it works for me (also GNU sed 4.2.2). But where did you get the idea that the OP wants spaces removed?

Comment: Compare the header ("field1|field2|...") lines in the examples

Comment: IT IS NOT WORKING. I AM GETTING THIS ERROR "N: Event not found."

Comment: @Shervan is probably using `csh` or `tcsh` where that `!` needs to be escaped, even inside single quotes.

Comment: oh. right. i apologize for my premature conclusion that he must have typed it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't want all those blank lines.

```
$ cat file
1|abc|def|ghi|
4|ijk|
|lmn|
5||opq|rst|
8|
uvw||xyz|
10|hjg|jsh|nbm|

$ awk -F'|' '{while (NF < 5) {getline nextline; $0 = $0 nextline}}1' file
1|abc|def|ghi|
4|ijk||lmn|
5||opq|rst|
8|uvw||xyz|
10|hjg|jsh|nbm|
```

---

Update for the question edit: remove whitespace around the field separator

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' -v OFS='|' '
    {while (NF < 5) {getline nextline; $0 = $0 nextline}; $1=$1; print} 
' file
```

Comment: genius solution !! what we call this process? may I kindly ask you to add some explanations for newbies like me. thank you!

Comment: Is there any particular bit you're unclear about? I assume a `while` loop is clear. `getline` reads the next line into the given variable. Then I concatentate the current line with the next line, and we re-check the number of fields. Other awk help can be found on the [tag:awk] tag info page.

Comment: Yes,  $0 = $0  and 1 at the end. thank you for any clarification!

Comment: It's not `$0=$0`, it's "assign to $0 the concatenation of $0 and nextline". awk doesn't have a concatenation operator: other languages might want `$0 = $0 + nextline`, but with awk you just put strings or variables side-by-side. For clarity we can write `$0 = ($0 nextline)`

Comment: The `1` is a common awk idiom that means "print the current record". Follow the link I gave and do some reading: it's well documented.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. Much inspired with your solution and detail explanation.

Comment: 2 queries i got after trying the commands are

Comment: 2 queries i got after trying the commands are.    1.i tried with both commands and didn't find any change in output result. Are both are doing the same work.   2. If I have a junk in fields like ab/c and r/st, how to validate and remove any junk characters from file

Comment: 1) the second command will remove spaces beside the pipe separators. 2) I don't understand your question -- you'll need to ask a separate question about this with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If using Vim is an option:

```
vim -Nesc 'g!/\(.*|\)\{4\}$/j!' -cwq input.txt
```

- `-Nes` runs Vim in script mode, making it easier to automate
- `-c ...` runs Vim commands after opening the file
- `g!/\(.*|\)\{4\}$/j!` - on every line [`:g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag), that *doesn't*  `!` match `/\(.*|\)\{4\}$/` (a regex matching 4 pipes separated by anything), join the next line to it ([`:j`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aj)).
- `wq` - save and quit.